# KeyBinding on a TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem, inputbinding, key-bindings

I have a typical treeview and a viewmodel. The viewmodel has an observable collection of other viewmodels that serves as a data source for the tree.

```
public class TreeViewVM {
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Items { get; private set; }
    public ItemVM SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

and the ItemVM :

```
public class ItemVM {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Children { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Rename { get; private set; }
}
```

The view :

```
<TreeView Selecteditem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                     <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding Rename}"/>
                 </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                 <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
```

However my command will not be invoked no matter what I try as long as it is "inside" the HierarchicalDataTemplate.

If I move the KeyBinding in the TreeView.InputBindings (and the ICommand / RelayCommand from the ItemVM to the TreeViewVM) all is nice, the command gets invoked.

But I would like to have the command on the ItemVM (as it is where it makes sense). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key binding would need to be defined on the TreeViewItem, as that is the element with the focus. The problem is you cannot define key bindings using a Style, which is what you'd probably want to do here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104601/xaml-how-to-have-global-inputbindings) is one workaround that uses a custom attached property to add items to the InputBinding collection via a Style. So you'd want to use something like that to define your Style, which you'd assign to TreeView.ItemContainerStyle.

Answer (score 8):

> But I would like to have the command on the ItemVM (as it is where it makes sense). Any ideas?

If `TreeViewVM` tracks the selected item through the `SelectedItem` property you can define `InputBindings` on `TreeView` and still have the commands implemented on the `ItemVM`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <TreeView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding SelectedItem.Rename}"/>
  </TreeView.InputBindings>
</TreeView>
```

Notice how the subproperty syntax `SelectedItem.Rename` is employed to use the `ItemVM` as the source of the binding.

Unfortunately, it is slightly tedious to bind to the selected item on a `TreeView`. You cannot bind directly to `SelectedItem` (as your XAML seems to suggest) but there exist [various methods to overcome this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153813/wpf-mvvm-treeview-selecteditem).

One simple method is to use [Blend Interactivity](http://nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Blend.Interactivity):

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=treeView}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

You will have to implement a `SetSeletectedItemCommand` on `TreeViewVM` that sets the property `SelectedItem`.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks for pointing out **SelectedItem**.Rename.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, please, see my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865204/keybinding-in-hierarchicaldatatemplate-of-treeview