# KeyBinding in HierarchicalDataTemplate of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a `TreeView`. I would like to enable `EditLeafCommand` by clicking **F2**.

**Model:**

```
public class Leaf
{
    public string LeafName { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }        
}
```

**ViewModel of Window:**

```
public MainWindowViewModel{

  public ReadOnlyCollection<LeafViewModel> Leafs
  {
        get { return leafs; }
  }
}
```

**ViewModel of TreeView:**

```
public class LeafViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }
    public string LeafName { get; set; }   
    public RelayCommand EditLeafCommand { get; set; }     

}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Leafs}">               
   <TreeView.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding SelectedItem.EditLeafCommand, 
                           diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
   </TreeView.InputBindings>
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LeafViewModel}" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">               
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LeafName}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnlyItem}" 
            Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
               <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                  <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                     <MenuItem Command="{Binding EditLeafCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ALeaf}" Header="Edit" />
                  </ContextMenu>
               </TextBox.ContextMenu>
            </TextBox>
         </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

and **Output window**:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=2683661) for Binding (hash=47044325)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'EditLeafCommand'
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Default mode resolved to OneWay
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Attach to 
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyBinding.Command (hash=29578451)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 64 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Use Framework mentor
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Framework mentor not found
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Resolve source deferred
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Got InheritanceContextChanged event from KeyBinding (hash=29578451)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Found data context element: TreeView (hash=11903911) (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): Activate with root item MainWindowViewModel (hash=44115416)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661):   At level 0 - for MainWindowViewModel.EditLeafCommand found accessor
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'EditLeafCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=44115416)'. BindingExpression:Path=EditLeafCommand; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=44115416); target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=29578451); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): TransferValue - using fallback/default value
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=2683661): TransferValue - using final value

I see this post and [it is it is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142509/keybinding-on-a-treeviewitem#14480647), however, accepted answer does not have any code(I've tried  to go through link, however, the offered approach didn't help me)

The error says:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :BindingExpression path error: 'EditLeafCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel'

But how can I direct to `EditLeadViewModel`?

**How can I call `EditLeafCommand` from `LeafViewModel` and send parameter?**

Comment: I don't see any XAML where you are binding to SetSelectedItemCommand, that seems to be the problem XAML, where is it?

Comment: Yes I can see there is no property called SetSelectedItemCommand, but there must be somewhere in the XAML that is doing `{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}`

Comment: @GlenThomas please, see my updated answer. I've updated info and I would like to bind to `LeafViewModel`, not `MainViewModel`. They are really stupid mistakes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andy ONeill has solved this problem.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f57a0a0-ed0d-4ba1-87af-9ced4d8cf8d0/keybinding-in-hierarchicaldatatemplate-of-treeview?forum=wpf) I am really excited by his solution:). I hurry to share this solution with you:

To bind to a command in `LeafViewModel`:

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Leafs}" Name="tv">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LeafViewModel}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="WingDings" Content="1"/>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding LeafName}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Background="Transparent">
                  <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                     <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding EditLeafCommand}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding ALeaf}" Header="Edit" />
                     </ContextMenu>
                  </TextBox.ContextMenu>
               </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding SelectedItem.EditLeafCommand, ElementName=tv}"/>
    </TreeView.InputBindings>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `MainViewModel` does not have a `SelectedItem` property. You need to add this property to your view model and make sure that the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event is fired when that property changes.

You also need to update this property whenever the selected item of the tree view changes. There are various ways to do that. One way is to use the Nuget package [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/). You will have to add a namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Then, inside your tree view XAML element add the following (I'm only showing what to add - keep the rest of your XAML inside the `TreeView` element intact):

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Leafs}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=treeView}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

Note that the `TreeView` element has a name (`treeView`) that is used in the `CommandParameter` binding in the `InvokeCommandAction` element.

Also, note that you have to add a `SetSelectedItemCommand` on `MainViewModel`. This command should set the `SelectedItem` property that I described in my initial paragraph. Here are some code fragments using a generic [`RelayCommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816/98607):

```
class MainWindowViewModel {

  TreeViewItemViewModel selectedItem;

  public MainWindowViewModel() {
    SetSelectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand<TreeViewItemViewModel>(SetSelectedItem);
  }

  public TreeViewItemViewModel SelectedItem {
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set {
      selectedItem = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  void SetSelectedItem(TreeViewItemViewModel viewModel) {
    SelectedItem = viewModel;
  }

}
```

This is the the basic stuff needed to enable your key binding to `SelectedItem.EditLeafCommand` to work. However, you have another problem. Your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` defines a tree node to be a `TextBox`. When you click on a `TextBox` no click is bubbled to the `TreeView` and the selection is not changed. My suggestion is that you use a non-interactive representation of each tree node (e.g. a `TextBlock`). Then, when `EditLeafCommand` is invoked you put a `TextBox` on top allowing the user to edit the node.