# WPF Commands, How to declare Application level commands?

Tags: wpf, routed-commands

I'm interested in creating commands that are available from anywhere in my WPF application.

I'd like them to work in the same way as `Cut`, `Copy`, `Paste` and the other Application level commands, ie:

```
<Button Command="Paste" />
```

I assumed I could setup CommandBindings for the Application instance, but that property isn't available.

How is this done?

The best I have managed so far is to create a suite of commands on the top level window and then access them like this...:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static namespace::MainWindow.CommandName}" />
```

Which works, but is of course tightly coupled, and so extremely brittle.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can setup CommandBindings for "All Windows" of your WPF application and implement command handlers in Application class.

First of all, create a static command container class. For example,

```
namespace WpfApplication1 
{
    public static class MyCommands
    {
        private static readonly RoutedUICommand doSomethingCommand = new RoutedUICommand("description", "DoSomethingCommand", typeof(MyCommands));

        public static RoutedUICommand DoSomethingCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return doSomethingCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, set your custom command to Button.Command like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Button Command="local:MyCommands.DoSomethingCommand">Execute</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Finally, implement the command handler of your custom command in Application class.

```
namespace WpfApplication1 
{

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var binding = new CommandBinding(MyCommands.DoSomethingCommand, DoSomething, CanDoSomething);

            // Register CommandBinding for all windows.
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), binding);
        }

        private void DoSomething(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }

        private void CanDoSomething(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shou, I'll give this a try. I assume I can use new command names e.g. `ApplicationCommands.MyCommand`? If not this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Please change the example to use a custom command, not Paste. I am unable to find any other reference to adding new commands to `ApplicationCommands`, can you provide a link? - Also, would you show XAML usage, esp if it differs from `<Button Command="MyCommand" />` - thank you.

Comment: I changed sample code. You don't have to add new commands to ApplicationCommands class because if you create a static command container class, it can be used just like ApplicationCommands class.

Comment: Thank you, that's great, and solves the issue of tight-coupling, which was the most important one for me.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 7):

I did not like the complexity of the other solutions, but after a few hours of research I found out it is really simple.

First setup your command as you usually do, but add a static property for WPF so that it can obtain an instance of your command.

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    // Singleton for the simple cases, may be replaced with your own factory     
    public static ICommand Instance { get; } = new MyCommand();

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true; // TODO: Implement
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // TODO: Implement       
    }   
}
```

Add a reference to the namespace of your command in your XAML (last line), like this:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:MyProject.Commands">
```

Then just reference your static property in your XAML like this:

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="commands:MyCommand.Instance" />
```

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow members helped me so many time that I decide now to contribute and share ;-)

Based on Shou Takenaka's answer,  here is my implementation.

My interest was to produce only **one reusable file**.

---

First, create a command(s) container class

```
namespace Helpers
{
    public class SpecificHelper
    {
        private static RoutedUICommand _myCommand = new RoutedUICommand("myCmd","myCmd", typeof(SpecificHelper));
        public static RoutedUICommand MyCommand { get { return _myCommand; } }

        static SpecificHelper()
        {
            // Register CommandBinding for all windows.
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(MyCommand, MyCommand_Executed, MyCommand_CanExecute));
        }

        // TODO: replace UIElement type by type of parameter's binded object
        #region MyCommand
        internal static void MyCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!verifType<UIElement>(e.Parameter)) return;

            e.Handled = true;
            // TODO : complete the execution code ...
        }

        internal static void SelectAll_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!verifType<UIElement>(e.Parameter)) return;

            e.CanExecute = true;
            var item = (e.Parameter as UIElement);
            // TODO : complete the execution code ...
        }
        #endregion

        private static bool verifType<T>(object o)
        {
            if (o == null) return false;
            if (!o.GetType().Equals(typeof(T))) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Next, declare a resource in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Helper.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:h="clr-namespace:Helpers"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >
    <Application.Resources>
        <h:SpecificHelper x:Key="sh" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

Finally, bind any command property to the property of your application resource:

```
<Button Content="Click to execute my command"
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource sh}, Path=MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myElement}" />
```

that's all folks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to define `CommandBindings` or `InputBindings` as resources in your `App.xaml`, you will find that you cannot use them, because XAML doesn't allow you to use either:

```
<Window ... CommandBindings="{StaticResource commandBindings}">
```

or to set command bindings with a style setter:

```
<Setter Property="CommandBindings" Value="{StaticResource commandBindings}">
```

because neither of these properties have a "set" accessor.  Using the idea in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104601/xaml-how-to-have-global-inputbindings), I came up with a clean way of using resources from `App.xaml` or any other resource dictionary.

First you define your command bindings and input bindings indirectly, like you would any other resource:

```
    <InputBindingCollection x:Key="inputBindings">
        <KeyBinding Command="Help" Key="H" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    </InputBindingCollection>
    <CommandBindingCollection x:Key="commandBindings">
        <CommandBinding Command="Help" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </CommandBindingCollection>
```

and then you refer to them from the XAML of another class:

```
<Window ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:CollectionSetterBehavior Property="InputBindings" Value="{StaticResource inputBindings}"/>
        <local:CollectionSetterBehavior Property="CommandBindings" Value="{StaticResource commandBindings}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
</Window>
```

The `CollectionSetterBehavior` is a reusable behavior that doesn't "set" the property to it's value, but instead clears the collection, and re-populates it.  So the collection doesn't change, only it's contents.

Here's the source for the behavior:

```
public class CollectionSetterBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public string Property
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Property", typeof(string), typeof(CollectionSetterBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public IList Value
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(IList), typeof(CollectionSetterBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var propertyInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetProperty(Property);
        var property = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(AssociatedObject, null) as IList;
        property.Clear();
        foreach (var item in Value) property.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with behaviors, first add this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and add the corresponding reference to your project.

Comment: Please show how you'd then use these commands in XAML, e.g. `<Button Command="MyCustomCommand"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `CommandBinding` at `Application` level from where it can be re-used everywhere.

```
<Application.Resources>       
    <CommandBinding x:Key="PasteCommandKey" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In your `App.xaml.cs` file, define corresponding handlers :

```
  private void CommandBinding_CanExecute_11(object sender, System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      e.CanExecute = false;
    }
```

**Usage**

In any xaml file, use it like below :

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="Rtb1" ContextMenuOpening="Rtb1_ContextMenuOpening_1" FontSize="15" Margin="10,10,10,-73">            
        <RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="PasteCommandKey"/>
        </RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: Given the explanations and quality of the answers already posted. Your answer isn't really adding value.  Please avoid posting code without explanation.  I recommend editing your answer to explain first, and show code second.  Thank you.

Comment: This very specific answer helped me a lot. Nobody else said that it's possible to put `<CommandBinding>` inside `<Application.Resources>`. @ocodo your comment is invalid.

Comment: @Endrju - please look at dates and edit history before you comment