# How to specify Command binding scope in MVVM?

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I'm messing around with MVVM and I've hit a bit of a roadblock with binding commands to buttons. I have a few buttons in a View ( = UserControl) that are generated based on a list of objects I have.

My code looks like this:

(MainWindow)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" Margin="12,57,12,12" />
```

(UserControl)

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllConnections}" Margin="0,34,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Password}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding Path=ConnectCommand}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But ConnectCommand isn't being called and I assume it's because XAML is looking for it in the AllConnections binding, rather than the ViewModels binding where it should. How do I specify this?

Comment: Button Content="{Binding Password}" - is properly binded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Relative source to specify the ancestor. Something like this:

```
Command = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ViewModel.CommandToBind}"
```

Comment: yep. It's depends on how you set the datacontext on the view

Answer (score 1):

You can add your command to Resources and just use `{StaticResource yourCommand}`. This could significally simplify xaml.

Useful links: 
[WPF Commands, How to declare Application level commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709906/wpf-commands-how-to-declare-application-level-commands)
[Commands as XAML Resources](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2010/03/commands-as-xaml-resources.html)
[MVVM Commanding inside of a datatemplate](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/162415/373144.aspx)